# Calculate time of session from logs in R

Tags: r

I have a nice dateset that includes user logins to my website, but no user logout. The user can access again the next day and then another line is registered. I'm looking to calculate how much time each user spent on the site.

The working assumption is that the site is quite interactive, and one can assume that the time between the first and last action is the time the user was on the site. The problem starts with a final action definition. For example, a user can be on the same page all night too, but this is unlikely (without taking any action). It is very clear to me how to calculate it in reality, but haven't been able to find a proper code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_csv(url("https://srv-file9.gofile.io/download/eBInE9/sheet1.csv"))

df %>% group_by(`User ID`)
lag(df$Time,1)

##Now I am wondering how to cluster the itemsn by time and to calculate lags..
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I hope this is better..

Comment: The trick is to ask yourself is the question reproducible? If you can start in a clean R session, copy the data and code from the question, run the code and get the same problem or output then you have the makings of a reproducible question. If not then it;s not easy for anyone to test and verify potential solutions to your question. Have a go and see what happens...

Comment: Thanks, I have tried making it simpler. However I am still stuck in the beginning of the code, so it's really an idea question and not only a code question..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the csv file you read has a `POSIXct` column which contains the login time. If not, you should make sure this exists.
Here's some code which generates time differences using the `lag` function by ID. The first time difference for each group will be `NA`. I generate some random time data first as you have not provided sample data (as you should have).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)


random_times <- seq(as.POSIXct('2020/01/01'), as.POSIXct('2020/02/01'), by="1 mins")
login <- tibble(login = sort(sample(random_times[hour(random_times) > "00:00" & hour(random_times) < "23:59"], 1000)),
                ID = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 1000, replace = TRUE))
login <- login %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(login_delayed = lag(login, 1)) %>%
  mutate(login_time = login - login_delayed)
```

With this output:

```
> login
# A tibble: 1,000 x 4
# Groups:   ID [6]
   login               ID    login_delayed       login_time
   <dttm>              <chr> <dttm>              <drtn>    
 1 2020-01-01 01:03:00 A     NA                   NA mins  
 2 2020-01-01 01:11:00 A     2020-01-01 01:03:00   8 mins  
 3 2020-01-01 01:46:00 E     NA                   NA mins  
 4 2020-01-01 02:33:00 E     2020-01-01 01:46:00  47 mins  
 5 2020-01-01 02:47:00 A     2020-01-01 01:11:00  96 mins  
 6 2020-01-01 10:43:00 F     NA                   NA mins  
 7 2020-01-01 11:44:00 A     2020-01-01 02:47:00 537 mins  
 8 2020-01-01 11:57:00 A     2020-01-01 11:44:00  13 mins  
 9 2020-01-01 12:02:00 F     2020-01-01 10:43:00  79 mins  
10 2020-01-01 12:57:00 D     NA                   NA mins  
# ... with 990 more rows
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried something like this -

`logs <- logs %>% 
  group_by(hashed) %>% 
  mutate(lag1 = lag(logs$timedate))`
But got this error - `Column `lag1` must be length 1 (the group size), not 1184`

Comment: If you like a precise response please share a sample of your data. In the `dplyr pipe` you should use column names and not use the `$` operator for column extraction. What happens is that you call the entire column `logs$timedate` instead of the relevant group. Try `logs <- logs %>% group_by(hashed) %>% mutate(lag1 = lag(timedate))` assuming `timedate` is a column in your dataset.